# Error on build npm package for react redux

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, redux

i'm creating an HOC to connect container and representational component.

I'm using webpack for build both on development test and production.

The package exports a function that return the react-redux connect component

On develempent everything works as expected. When i build the package and link to test in production build i got

> Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(NameComponentPres)". Either wrap the root component in a `<Provider>`, or pass a custom React context provider to `<Provider>` and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(NameComponentPres) in connect options.

i don't think that is a problem with react because it works on development.

this is my configuration

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");


const outputPath = process.env.BUILD
   ? path.resolve("./build")
   : path.resolve("./test");

const testConfig = {
   mode: "development",
   entry: "./demo/index.js",
   devtool: "inline-source-map",
   externals: "./build/redux-simple-container.js",
   output: {
       path: outputPath,
       filename: "index.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            include: [path.resolve("./demo")]
        }
    ]
  }
};

const buildConfig = {
  entry: "./src/ReduxSimpleContainer.js",
  mode: "production",
  output: {
      path: outputPath,
      filename: "redux-simple-container.js",
      libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
  },
  externals: ["react", "react-dom"],
  module: {
      rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            use: "babel-loader",
            exclude: /(node_modules)/
        }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = process.env.BUILD ? buildConfig : testConfig;
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [["airbnb", { "modules": false }]],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-assign"]
}
```

./src/ReduxSimpleContainer.js

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
const ReduxSimpleContainer = (actions, stateRequested, Component) => {
  ....
  ....
  return connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(Component);
};

export default ReduxSimpleContainer;
```

Comment: In your build config your `test` in rules is not picking up `.jsx` files while your test config is. If you are using that extension, that would cause issues. Also, if you could provide the entry point files in the question, that'd be helpful for diagnosis of this particular issue.

Comment: i'm using .js extension.. code added @Jclangst

Comment: where did you put the provider store

Comment: provider store is separate from the package file..
I use the function to simplify the connection between the components. the provider is not tied to the package..i have used it in 3/4 projects and now i want to use it via npm @godfather